# SMS Manager in iOS

Tags: ios, sms, smsmanager, core-telephony

Android offers Telephony API, that provides SMSManager, and also method "sendTextMessage" - which can be used by apps to send messages.

Also, received message broadcasts can be delivered as intent to the default SMS app, when new messages are received.

What are the equivalent APIs in Apple iOS which can be used to send and receive SMS? 
And are these APIs available for use by third party messaging applications. If not, how can third-party apps send and receive SMS?

Comment: You can send text messages (with user interaction) using `MFMessageComposeViewController`.  There are no APIs for accessing text messages that have been received or sending messages without user interaction.  You could use a service such as Twilio to send and receive messages, but these messages won't be sent from/to the user's cellular number

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11 for your response. From what I understand, MFMessageComposeViewController provides a standard user interface for composing SMS within an application. However, sending an SMS would require  iOS system services, which would be available to the application that actually performs the task of sending and receiving. Will this be performed by the pre-installed iOS Messages app? And if so, does Apple provide any information about the methods/ functions in iOS which are used by the preinstalled Messages app to send/ receive messages?

Comment: `MFMessageComposeViewController` is the only api available to send messages within an app. You can open an `sms:` URL to launch the messages app. Whatever the iOS messages app uses to actually send and receive messages is not available for use by apps